# What to do in ModelBuilder after adding layers and dragging tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I'm trying to create a model that would Merge two layers and then do a Summarize to a common attribute/field between them.

The process I'm doing is getting into the ModelBuilder then adding the 2 layers, then Drag the merge tool into it, then I'm lost!

Is there any possible way to correct my steps or add any steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PolyGeo has it right, you must connect the data, in this case both datasets need to be connected to the merge command.

It seems though you may be a little confused about what you are trying to do. The [merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000055000000) tool takes the two inputs and puts them together into one output: If you have shapefiles A and B and merge them to C then C contains all of the features in A and B.

From the wording of your question I think that you really want to [join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000064000000) A to B over a common field such that you have features in A which contains values from B also.

Either way to summarize the data you want [summary statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/) to get minimum, maximum, sum... of values using *case* fields. A case field, or collection of fields, will become a row in the summary table where each unique value (or unique combination) is presented with the statistics for that value or combination.

Put these tools into your model and use PolyGeos' advice on connecting them.

Comment: After Infollowed your process now everything is being clear to understand and just to mention that I stayed up late and learned things about the whole process.. Here it goes: drag A + B shapefiles .. Drag Merge and then connected them to the Merge then changed the output to parameters so that I can run the model from the toolbox directly without getting into the modelbuilder. But now all I want is that to Summarize the output of a specific field. So the model will  merge shapefiles then summarize a specific field automatically.. I'm fast learner but I want to make sure... Thank you sir!

Comment: connect the output of one tool into the next tool. In this case the merged data (should be green) connects to summary statistics, then double click on the yellow box and fill in the details. That is the basics, it gets more confusing when you want to save the model to get feature classes as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to ***connect*** your data and tool.

This is described in a documentation page entitled [**Adding and connecting data and tools**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Adding_and_connecting_data_and_tools/002w0000002r000000/) under the heading **Connecting data and tools**.

> There are two ways to connect variables to tool parameters: using the
>   Connect tool or the tool's dialog box.

Comment: After Infollowed your process now everything is being clear to understand and just to mention that I stayed up late and learned things about the whole process.. Here it goes: drag A + B shapefiles .. Drag Merge and then connected them to the Merge then changed the output to parameters so that I can run the model from the toolbox directly without getting into the modelbuilder. But now all I want is that to Summarize the output of a specific field. So the model will  merge shapefiles then summarize a specific field automatically.. I'm fast learner but I want to make sure... Thank you sir!

Comment: That's good news! With your original question answered I think you should accept (green tick) one of the answers and decide whether to apply any upvotes or downvotes. If you have follow up questions then research/ask these separately as per the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) guidelines.